# xCode - UITableView compacted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have a table view with section and i would like to start the table view with all section grouped like this:

```
Section1  
Section2  
Section3
```

When i tap on a section title, it expand the rows

```
Section1
 Row1
 Row2
 Row3
Section2
Section3
```

Comment: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/

Answer (score 0):

**i requested to all please see the answer if you dont like,just comment**

**this is for beginners....**

**this code also refered from net only and i changed few things**

[this link](https://github.com/liuxiangyu-kx/lvyou/blob/master/ViewController.m)

creat class file...

**ViewController.h** file should be

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "oneViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"
#import "thirdViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    oneViewController *one;
    secondViewController *second;
    thirdViewController *third;
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m** file should be

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Cell1.h"
#import "Cell2.h"
@interface ViewController()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *dataList;

}
@property (assign)BOOL isOpen;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSIndexPath *selectIndex;

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *expansionTableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize isOpen,selectIndex;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [dataList release];
    dataList= nil;
    self.expansionTableView = nil;
    self.isOpen = NO;
    self.selectIndex = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        one=[[oneViewController alloc]init ];
        second=[[secondViewController alloc]init];
        third=[[thirdViewController alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"array" ofType:@"plist"];
    dataList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)dataList.count);
    self.expansionTableView.sectionFooterHeight = 0;
    self.expansionTableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
    self.isOpen = NO;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [dataList count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.isOpen) {
        if (self.selectIndex.section == section) {
            return [[[dataList objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"list"] count]+1;

        }

    }
    return 1;
}
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"%@",[[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"list"] );
    if (self.isOpen&&indexPath.section == indexPath.section&&indexPath.row!=0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
        Cell2 *cell = (Cell2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        if ([[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"list"])
        {
            NSArray *list = [[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"list"];
            cell.titleLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
            return cell;
        }

        return cell;
    }else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
        Cell1 *cell = (Cell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        NSString *name = [[dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"name"];
        cell.titleLabel.text = name;
        //[cell changeArrowWithUp:([indexPath isEqual:indexPath]?YES:NO)];
        if ([indexPath isEqual:indexPath])
        {
            [cell changeArrowWithUp:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell changeArrowWithUp:NO];
        }
        return cell;
    }

}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectIndex]) {
            Cell1 *cell = (Cell1 *)[self.expansionTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectIndex];
            [cell changeArrowWithUp:YES];
            self.isOpen = NO;
            [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:NO];
            self.selectIndex = nil;

        }else
        {
            if (!self.selectIndex) {
                self.selectIndex = indexPath;
                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:YES nextDo:NO];
                Cell1 *cell = (Cell1 *)[self.expansionTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectIndex];
                [cell changeArrowWithUp:NO];


            }else
            {
                NSIndexPath *tempIndex=indexPath;
                if (tempIndex)
                {
                    Cell1 *cell = (Cell1 *)[self.expansionTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tempIndex];
                    [cell changeArrowWithUp:NO];

                }
                Cell1 *cell = (Cell1 *)[self.expansionTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectIndex];
                [cell changeArrowWithUp:YES];
                [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:NO nextDo:YES];
            }
        }

    }else
    {

        NSDictionary *dic = [dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSArray *list = [dic objectForKey:@"list"];
        NSString *item = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"sample tree" message:item delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

//        NSArray* temp=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:one,second,third,nil];
//        [self viewPresent:[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] sectionAt:item];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
//method for pushing view controller
-(void)viewPresent:(UIViewController *)viewName sectionAt:(NSString *)sectionValue
{
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:viewName animated:YES];
}

- (void)didSelectCellRowFirstDo:(BOOL)firstDoInsert nextDo:(BOOL)nextDoInsert
{
    self.isOpen = firstDoInsert;


    [self.expansionTableView beginUpdates];

    int section = self.selectIndex.section;
    int contentCount = [[[dataList objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"list"] count];
    NSMutableArray* rowToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < contentCount + 1; i++) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPathToInsert = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
        [rowToInsert addObject:indexPathToInsert];
    }

    if (firstDoInsert)
    {   [self.expansionTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.expansionTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }

    [rowToInsert release];

    [self.expansionTableView endUpdates];
    if (nextDoInsert) {
        self.isOpen = YES;
        self.selectIndex = [self.expansionTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [self didSelectCellRowFirstDo:YES nextDo:NO];
    }
//    if (self.isOpen) [self.expansionTableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
@end
```

then create two cell with subclass of **UITableViewCell**

the first cell should be

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell1 : UITableViewCell


@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *arrowImageView;

- (void)indication:(BOOL)up;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "Cell1.h"

@implementation Cell1
@synthesize titleLabel,arrowImageView;

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.titleLabel = nil;
    self.arrowImageView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)indication:(BOOL)up
{

    if (up) {

        self.arrowImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UpAccessory.png"];
    }else
    {
        self.arrowImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownAccessory.png"];

    }
}
```

the second cell should be

**.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell2 : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "Cell2.h"

@implementation Cell2
@synthesize titleLabel;
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.titleLabel = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

for learning purpose my values are like below

```
(
 {
     list =         (
                     1,
                     2,
                     3
                     );
     name = Numbers;
 },
 {
     list =         (
                     a,
                     b,
                     c
                     );
     name = Alaphabets;
 },
 {
     list =         (
                     India,
                     China,
                     Australia
                     );
     name = Countries;
 }
 )
```